# Error duplicate value for resource 'attr/borderColor' with config ''. when using me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I got this erorr when I use me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13 But when i use this me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9 it's work.

Can you solved my problem?

this my gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'

// lib for SMS verification (Phone Auth)
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.1.0'

// Material Dialog Library
implementation 'com.shreyaspatil:MaterialDialog:1.0.0'

// Lottie Animation Library
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.6'

// OTP

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.3'
implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.5@aar'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]use this may be
 there was issue of mistake 
 implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13' could not resolve while implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8' working fine

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

Comment: but if i use under 1.9.13, the scanner not showing at high level API like 27, and i have tried 1.9.8 still got error.